# Slope and trendline option giving two different values

Tags: excel, trendline

I have the following data:

```
d units m : (2481.7, 2483.5, 2486.1, 2488.5) 
p units psi: (3759.7, 3759.6, 3760.7, 3761.7)
```

and I have to find psi/m

I am using `=slope(p,d)` and it's giving me **0.3147** psi/m. But when I scatter plot d on the y-axis and p on the x axis and draw a linear trendline, the slope is 2.9233 m/psi. I found 1/2.9233 = **0.34207** psi/m, however the values in bold should be the same.

I also tried following, and it's giving absurd answers again

```
d: (2481.7, 2483.5, 2486.1, 2488.5)
p: (3759.7, 3759.6, 3760.7, 3761.7)
```

When I use `linest(d,p)`, the slope is 2.9297 m/psi, which translates to **0.341** psi/m, but when I use `linest(p,d)`, the slope is **0.314** psi/m. But the figures in bold should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to changing axis variable which in turn changes the variance